# How facebook store and access text data

Tags: mysql, facebook

I was trying to learn database design techniques by myself. As facebook is an example of huge data processing system, I was wondering how to process that huge amount data. I came to know they use MySQL as core database engine and ‘Memcached’ to cache data and reduce database access.

I just to want to know how they store text data like status or comments. Do they just store it in some table of MySQL database or use any kind of technique?

Additionally it will be a bonus if anyone can provide information about their storing technique for media like images or videos.
(If asking that kind of information about an organization is illegal or unethical then I am sorry for asking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two relevant notes from the Facebook engineering team

- [TAO: The power of the graph](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/tao-the-power-of-the-graph/10151525983993920)
- [Needle in a haystack: efficient storage of billions of photos](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=76191543919)